# Android Studio generated a wrong ViewBinding: android.viewbinding.ViewBinding

Tags: android-studio, android-viewbinding

When I tried to build my project with `viewBinding` enabled:

```
buildFeatures {
   viewBinding true
}
```

I got this weird binding file: `ActivityCameraBinding extends android.viewbinding.ViewBinding`

The problem here is the file should `extends androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding`. Although when I compiled and run the application, it's working, it caused the android studio shown red warning underlining `ActivityCameraBinding` in my project.

Is there any idea to resolve it?

Comment: it normally show like this `import com.example.app.databinding.ActivityCameraBinding;`. Can I show that code?

Comment: yes, it's like that: `mypackage.databinding.ActivityCameraBinding`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should migrate your project to AndroidX

Check in the `gradle.properties` file if `android.useAndroidX` and `android.enableJetifier` fields is true

For more information [AndroidX Overview](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx?gclid=Cj0KCQjw94WZBhDtARIsAKxWG--quEM-P4mdNAX5lBLV2z_xxeTTy9_c_euCHrIn5e5mIW5KijlvpY8aAsepEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds#using_androidx_libraries_in_your_project)